# Connecting to a WIFI appliance from a script?

Tags: linux, ssh

Sorry about the vague subject - this isn't about how to connect to WIFI, but about connecting to the access point from a command line, or rather in a script. I can do this manually with ssh, but there is no writable filesystem, so I can't upload a public key, and ssh doesn't seem to have an option for specifying a stored password, which of course is the right thing in general, but which is awkward in this case.

I know of paramiko, and it works if I run simple commands like `df` or `ps`, and there is a variant of `tcpdump` called `xtcpdump` - but it doesn't produce any output if I run it from paramiko.

Is it possible to get the normal, standard, command line ssh to accept a password in a script, without insisting it be input manually?